# EvtClearLog does not clear .evtx log files

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service, event-log

I have this line of code

```
EvtClearLog(NULL, L"C:\\Windows\\system32\\winevt\\logs\\Application.evtx", NULL, 0);
```

After running the line I get this error in the debugger

```
First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD6DB3DD in MyApp.exe:
Microsoft C++ exception: wmi::GenericException at memory location 0x000000000025B250.
```

The application runs when not in debugger without any error, but the Event log file is not cleared.

Comment: Have you read the documentation and verified your function arguments? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: And if EvtOpenLog can open a .evtx file and query for records, then why EvtClearLog would work only with channels? It seems that there is no way to clear the event log records of each log file.